# Terraform / alicloud : create an ECS instance with multiple data disks

Tags: terraform, alibaba-cloud, terraform0.12+, alibaba-cloud-ecs

I'm trying to create multiple ecs instances using terraform. In fact I want for each ecs instance to have multiple data disks. So one disk for OS and 2 other data disks.

The code snippet should look like :

```
resource "alicloud_instance" "node" {
  image_id                      = data.alicloud_images.nodes.id
  instance_type                 = var.instance_type_controller
  internet_max_bandwidth_out    = 100
  security_groups               = alicloud_security_group.cluster.id

  key_name = var.key_pair
  count    = 1

  system_disk_size              = 80

  data_disks                    = [
    {
      name                  = "/dev/xvdb"
      size                  = 200
      delete_with_instance  = true
    },
    {
      name                  = "/dev/xvdc"
      size                  = 100
      delete_with_instance  = true
    }
  ]
}
```

Only problem is that I have an message error telling me that

```
An argument named "data_disks" is not expected here. Did you mean to define a
block of type "data_disks"?
```

I went through the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/aliyun/alicloud/latest/docs/resources/instance#data_disks) and I am pretty sure that `data_disks` is of type `list(map(string))` so what I wrote should work but it only work when I set it as

```
data_disks {
      name                  = "/dev/xvdb"
      size                  = 200
      delete_with_instance  = true
}
```

But I need multiple data disks attached to my ECS instance... Am I missing something ?

I'm using the following terraform/provider versions :

```
Terraform v0.13.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/alicloud v1.94.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/random v2.3.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/template v2.1.2
```

Comment: You need to repeat the block multiple times.

Comment: Brilliant it worked like a charm, thanks @ydaetskcoR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ydaetskcoR commented. The solution is to have multiple `data_disks` blocks. So something like this:

```
resource "alicloud_instance" "node" {
  image_id                      = data.alicloud_images.nodes.id
  instance_type                 = var.instance_type_controller
  internet_max_bandwidth_out    = 100
  security_groups               = alicloud_security_group.cluster.id

  key_name = var.key_pair
  count    = 1

  system_disk_size              = 80
   
  data_disks {
      name                  = "/dev/xvdb"
      size                  = 200
      delete_with_instance  = true
  }

  data_disks {
      name                  = "/dev/xvdc"
      size                  = 100
      delete_with_instance  = true
  }
 
}
```